# splitting a string in which upper case follows lower case in stringr

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a string vector that looks like this and I'd like to split it up:

```
str <- c("Fruit LoopsJalapeno Sandwich", "Red Bagel", "Basil LeafBarbeque SauceFried Beef")

str_split(str, '[a-z][A-Z]', n = 3)

[[1]]
[1] "Fruit Loop"       "alapeno Sandwich"

[[2]]
[1] "Red Bagel"

[[3]]
[1] "Basil Lea"    "arbeque Sauc" "ried Beef"
```

But I need to keep those letters at the end and start of the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's 2 approaches in base (you can generalize to **stringr** if you want).

This one subs out this place with a placeholder and then splits on that.

```
strsplit(gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1SPLITHERE\\2", str), "SPLITHERE")

## [[1]]
## [1] "Fruit Loops"       "Jalapeno Sandwich"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "Red Bagel"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "Basil Leaf"     "Barbeque Sauce" "Fried Beef"
```

This method uses lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
strsplit(str, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "Fruit Loops"       "Jalapeno Sandwich"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "Red Bagel"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "Basil Leaf"     "Barbeque Sauce" "Fried Beef"
```

**EDIT** Generalized to **stringr**  so you can grab 3 pieces if you want

```
stringr::str_split(gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1SPLITHERE\\2", str), "SPLITHERE", 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also match instead of `split`ting based off your string.

```
unlist(regmatches(str, gregexpr('[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+', str)))
# [1] "Fruit Loops"       "Jalapeno Sandwich" "Red Bagel"        
# [4] "Basil Leaf"        "Barbeque Sauce"    "Fried Beef"
```

Comment: Nice and may be more efficient +1